# How to retrieve HTTP Code and Content from IActionResult?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I've 7 actions in my controllers. I've refactored them an was able to isolate the common portion.

```
public IActionResult Get()
{
    var response = CommonCode();
}

public IActionResult Get(guid id)
{
    var response = CommonCode();
}

public IActionResult Post(ViewModel vm)
{
    var response = CommonCode();
}
```

This is where I refactored the common code.

```
provate IActionResult CommonCode()
{
   if(userHasNoPermission())
     return Forbid();

   if(IdProvidedDoesntExist())
     return BadRequest();

   //...
}
```

When I look inside the `response`, I see only one method: `ExecuteResultAsync()`.

Is there a way to retrieve the HTTP code that I sent inside the helper method?

I'd like for instance to stop the processing if it's `500`, retrieve the message to add to the `ModelState*` if it's `400`, but proceed if it's `OK`.

Comment: Unfortunately `Forbid` returns a `ForbidResult` and `BadRequest` returns a `BadRequestResult` and the only common base class they have is `ActionResult` and that doesn't contain a `StatusCode` property. If you could change `Forbid` to a different response you may be able to change the return type to `StatusCodeResult`, which has the property you need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The return of `CommonCode` is simply some type of `IActionResult`. The "result" is not actually a "response". That comes later when the action is fully returned back into the request pipeline (which has not occurred yet when you're calling the method directly in code). As result, concepts like HTTP status code aren't even relevant yet. If you return something like `StatusCodeResult`, that's technically only a *suggested* status code. If there's an exception later in the request pipeline or some piece of middleware explicitly changes the status code for some reason, it will be different.

Long and short, you're trying to conflate two unrelated things together. I think you simply want to know what happened in `CommonCode`, and think the HTTP status is the best way to determine that. In actuality, you'd be better served by returning a tuple or doing something like pattern matching:

With a tuple, you can essentially return more than one thing from your `CommonCode` method. For example, you could do something like:

```
private (int, IActionResult) CommonCode()
{
   if(userHasNoPermission())
     return (403, Forbid());

   if(IdProvidedDoesntExist())
     return (400, BadRequest());

   //...
}
```

Then:

```
public IActionResult Get()
{
    (var status, var response) = CommonCode();
    // branch on `status`
}
```

Or, with pattern matching:

```
public IActionResult Get()
{
    var response = CommonCode();
    switch (response)
    {
        case ForbidResult forbid:
            // do something for forbidden
            break;
        case BadRequestResult badRequest:
            // do something for bad request
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I always thought a method could only return one value. I learned something new today...Is there an advantage of returning a tuple over say, returning a custom object with `status` and `response` as properties?

Comment: The advantage is only ease. It's problematic to have disposable classes all over the place in your code just two return two things instead of one. However, tuple returns used to be a bit of an antipattern because they were opaque. That situation improved with the introduction of ValueTuple and deconstruction in C#, and so returning tuples is not so bad now. That said, C# 9 introduced records which are really a better approach overall. They are immutable objects, somewhere between a struct and a class in nature, but much lighter weight than class.

Comment: If I was writing this answer today, I'd recommend a record instead.

Answer (score 11):

There are a few "filthy" ways you can do it without a case statement. The status code is actually in the result but IActionResult and ActionResult hate being cast to a common type.

This example takes a IActionResult from any common result and rips the status code out using reflection. If you don't mind doing it that way it saves requiring the case statement to pattern match. The same can be done for the content.

```
    public static HttpStatusCode GetHttpStatusCode(IActionResult functionResult)
    {
        try
        {
            return (HttpStatusCode)functionResult
                .GetType()
                .GetProperty("StatusCode")
                .GetValue(functionResult, null);
        }
        catch
        {
            return HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar problem returning `Ok()` and `NotFound()`. I
was able to get the status code using the `IStatusCodeActionResult` interface.

`((IStatusCodeActionResult)response).StatusCode`;

Comment: This is the best answer. I had a mix of types inheriting from StatusCodeResult and ObjectResult. Drilled down into definitions far enough to see they both share IStatusCodeActionResult implementation. Simple cast and voila! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You could return the statuscode itself from the private method. for example

```
private IActionResult CommonCode() {    
    if(userHasNoPermission())
     return StatusCode(401);

   if(IdProvidedDoesntExist())
     return StatusCode(400);

   //... }
```

then in your method just check for the status code

```
public IActionResult Post(ViewModel vm)
{
    var response = CommonCode();
    if (this.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode == 418)
       Console.WriteLine("I'm a teapot")

    else {
       return response;
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically an IActionResult can be casted to either StatusCodeResult (if the api does not return anything) or ObjectResult (if the api returns some data) from which you can get:

- The status code from *StatusCode* property (both StatusCodeResult and ObjectResult implements the interface you mentioned IStatusCodeActionResult)
- The actual result from the *Value* property (only for ObjectResult)

All ControllerBase methods like Ok, BadRequest, NotFound, Conflict are helper methods to return OkObjectResult, BadRequestObjectResult, NotFoundObjectResult, ConflictObjectResult which are all derived classes from ObjectResult.

Comment: I can't cast a `ForbidResult` to either of those types (`StatusCodeResult `, `ObjectResult `) // .net7

Comment: @Vetras yep, but you can replace "return Forbid();" with "return StatusCode((int) HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);" (StatusCode is another helper method of [ControllerBase](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ControllerBase.cs#L219-L220)) As you noted Forbid does not implement ObjectResult because it should be returned by asp.net core even without invoking the controller action according to Authorize attribute, if you instead implemented a custom authorization code inside your controller action you can return any status code you want using the StatusCode method.